# vc++ - How to convert a CString into LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I tried to do this , but I didn't find any method for this. I am asking this due to the fact that I am new to windows. I tried stl-strings, but visual studio 2008- accumulates bugs in stl-wstring-handling. I will say a lot about that thing later, in other question. Now Can anybody shed light on this issue?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to use the MFC String Conversion Macros, defined at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/string-conversion-macros?view=msvc-160

For example, the macro to convert `CString` to `LPCWSTR` is `CT2W(s)`.

Another way is to use the specialized `CStringA` and `CStringW` classes. These are the corresponding ascii and wide versions of `CString` depending on if you're compile with the `UNICODE` flag. So you can use:

```
CString your_string = "blah"
CStringW wide_string = your_string;
```

to get a wide version of your string.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it, assuming your application isn't already set to Unicode (if it is, just cast directly):

```
CString str("Hello, world!");
CStringW strw(str);
LPCWSTR ptr = strw;
```

Comment: So many convoluted (and right-out wrong) answers, and the only correct way to do this in MFC (through conversion c'tors) didn't get any upvotes?

Answer (score 6):

Use the conversion class CT2CW like this `FuncTakingLPCWSTR(CT2CW(cstring_var))`. This is guaranteed to work in either Unicode or MBCS builds.

Also, keep in mind that the string passed to the function may be a temporary, so don't store it for later use.

Answer (score 2):

```
LPCWSTR pstr;
CString cstrTemp;

...

pstr = cstrTemp.AllocSysString();
```

AllocSysString will return a BSTR type string, that can be converted to LPCWSTR directly.

Comment: A `BSTR` cannot be converted to an `LPCWSTR`. Both string types have different semantics. For example, `nullptr` is always a valid `BSTR`. `LPCWSTR` doesn't make any guarantees. Besides, a `BSTR` needs to be cleaned up calling `SysFreeString`. Your code doesn't show this, and your explanation doesn't note this either. Since the OP is asking for a **const** pointer, chances are they do not even need a copy. In that case, the built-in `operator LPCTSTR()` may be sufficient already. And really, unless you need a `BSTR`, don't just use one because you don't know what else to do. Sorry, -1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `UNICODE,_UNICODE` compiler flags defined then a simple assignment should work. If you have `_MBCS` defined you need to use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/108450) method.

Comment: Overly complex in MFC. Better use CStringW as suggested, or an appropriate Cx2y class.

Comment: `CString` has conversion c'tors. If you need a wide character string from an ANSI-encoded string, simply do `CStringW wideString(narrowString);`, where `narrowString` is of type `CStringA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use T2W() macro to avoid writing several lines of MultiByteToWideChar code.

Comment: Better use the Cx2y classes instead of the old T-macros.